# Error: No Such Table After Creating SQLite table in phpLiteAdmin

Tags: database, sqlite

I've made a table called `transactions` in a pre-existing database called `finance.db` that already contains a table called `users`. I'm using phpLiteAdmin to view the database.  I created the `transactions` table with the following statement:

```
create table 'transactions' (
    'tx_id' integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT unique not null,
    'ticker' text unique not null,
    'security' text unique not null,
    'price' numeric not null,
    'shares' integer not null,
    'tx_type' integer not null,
    'date' datetime default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not null,
    'user_id' integer not null,
    foreign key (user_id) references users(id)
    );
```

Upon executing the above statement, the `transactions` table appeared in the database. I then thought the `tx_type` field might be better as a boolean, rather than an integer, as it will only take one of two values. I went into phpLiteAdmin to change the data type using a dropdown box and the application threw the following error: `ERROR: no such table: temp.users`

I have no clue what is going on, as I have zero experience with SQLite or phpLiteAdmin. However, it seems that phpLiteAdmin does not want to recognise that this table is, in fact, part of the database even though it is displayed therein and tied to a pre-existing table via a foreign key.

Any thoughts on what is happening?

Comment: Does users table that you used in your transaction table actually exist?

Comment: From what I can tell, yes. I've registered users, stored password hashes, logged in, and logged out of the site. If it didn't exist, none of this should be possible. Note, however, I tried the above transactions table once before. It too interacted with my website and *still* threw the above error when I went into phpLiteAdmin to make a change. This is a new version of that table.

Comment: Does it exist in "temp" db?

Comment: Unless I'm reading the screen really, really wrong, both tables exist in finance.db.

Comment: Check the error `ERROR: no such table: temp.users` it says temp.users

Comment: Yeah, I can't account for it. Here's what's on my "Structure Tab"

Comment: Database name: finance
Path to database: /home/ubuntu/workspace/pset7/finance/finance.db